# ListView toggle item between checked and unchecked - Android

Tags: android, listview

In android, you can set an item in the ListView as checked by doing this: `lv.setItemChecked
(pos,true)` and set an item as unchecked by `lv.setItemChecked(pos,false)`

but how do you toggle between checked and unchecked, meaning: if the item is checked then uncheck it and vice versa

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**An example is worth a thousand words:**

```
public void toggle(lv,pos){
    if (lv.isItemChecked(pos)) {

        lv.setItemChecked(pos,false);

    } else {

        lv.setItemChecked(pos,true);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

ListView has a method called `isItemChecked(int)` that returns a boolean. Try the following:

```
if (lv.isItemChecked(pos)) {

    lv.setItemChecked(pos,false);

} else {

    lv.setItemChecked(pos,true);

}
```

More on `ListView.isItemChecked(int)`: [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#isItemChecked%28int%29)

Comment: `lv.setItemChecked(pos, !lv.isItemChecked(pos));`